# Does can Zabbix send log in mail after fail restart service

Tags: logging, notifications, monitoring, zabbix, email-notifications

I have one question about Zabbix Action functions.

I configured some trigger, example for MySQL down. For this trigger I created Zabbix Action with 2 Steps.

Step 1. Zabbix run remote script to restart MySQL service. After 1 minutes if service still down zabbix run the second step.

Step 2. Zabbix send email.

My question is:

Can I add the last 15 rows of mysql-error.log in that mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change the default zabbix email by customs scripts. This script will read the last 15 lines of log file and then append this lines in the email.

Access Zabbix with a admin account and then Administration, Media Types, Create Media Type choose type = script.
In "Script Name" put the name of the script ou create do send email. **This script must be in ZABBIX_HOME/alertscripts.**

Configure your action to use this media type.

The [docs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/notifications/media/script) are always your friend

Comment: Thank you on answer. Yes I know fo that. But I think, maybe someone was actualy doing something similar direct from Zabbix. In anyway thank you on sugestion. I will try.